# Get number of rows of all variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset in few csv files (each csv is a set of different columns but with the same number of rows). After importing all csv files to R I want to merge this data into one table.

As a progress check I would like to check if all imported files have the same number of rows, just in case.

So far I figure out this part:

```
lapply(lapply(ls(),get),nrow)
```

Unfortunately this way I'm getting numbers of rows without variables names.

Is there a way to extract number of rows together with variable names?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check

```
a <- matrix(0, 3)
b <- matrix(0, 2)
setNames(lapply(lapply(ls(),get),nrow), ls())
$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 2
```

You might also prefer

```
setNames(sapply(mget(ls()),nrow), ls())
a b 
3 2
```

Comment: You could make it compact by `lapply(mget(ls()),nrow)`